# Search does not work like expect in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In  my application i use a search input to search values, and select input also to filter values from my data. Now my component looks like below:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [myData, setMydata] = useState([]);
  const searchData = e => {
    const v = e.target.value;
    const res= data.filter(i =>
      i.name.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase())
    );
    setMydata(res);
  };
  function handleChange(value) {
    const res= data.filter(i => i.age === Number(value));
    setMydata(res);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select defaultValue="" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleChange}>
        <Option value="2">2</Option>
        <Option value="32">32</Option>
      </Select>
      <input onChange={searchData} />
      <h1>Data</h1>
      {myData.map((i, k) => (
        <div key={k}>
          {i.name} is <span>{i.age}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, the functionality works. If you search something, appear results, and if you try to select a value, also appears the value that you selected.
**Issue**: If i select from dropdown, for example: `32`, appears:

```css
Julia is 32
Bill is 32
Bill is 32
```

And now if i want to search from the list above just `Julia`, i type Julia in search, it search from the whole list of data, not just from the list which i get after i selected `32`. 
How to solve this, and how to get the result from the last results, not to search from the whole list, but from the last result?

*Note*: the same issue is when i search first and after that i select a value from dropdown.

Comment: You need to *store* both the selected age *and* the input, so that both can be used to filter the array.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what do you mean, how it does look?

Answer (score 2):

Your two filters always work with the same object `data`, and not previously filtered state data `myData`. Best practice save value of filters in state and each render filter data:

```
export default function App() {
    const [age, setAge] = useState('');
    const [name, setName] = useState('');

    const filteredData = data
        .filter(i => Boolean(age) ? i.age === Number(age) : true)
        .filter(i => i.name.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase()));

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Select value={age} style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={setAge}>
                <Option value="2">2</Option>
                <Option value="32">32</Option>
            </Select>
            <input value={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} />
            <h1>Data</h1>
            {filteredData.map((i, k) => (
                <div key={k}>
                    {i.name} is <span>{i.age}</span>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: the code works, but when i wanted to add additional filter, it does not work https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hamilton-s4xt9?file=/src/App.js . Could you please, say how to  make working the third `.filter`> because now if i search i don't get anything, but if i select from calendar   today's day, appears the result. Why the code not working? Thanks

Comment: @Asking Add filter selection check, like age filter in my example above `.filter(i => Boolean(date) ? date.includes(i.date) : true);`

Comment: what mean when we return `true`? How i understand, the condition is next:  `Boolean(date)` -if `date` is true, do this: `date.includes(i.date)`, and if not do: `true`. What mean true in this condition?

Comment: @Asking `filter` method is waiting return boolean for each element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter `Boolean(date)` - transformation string to boolean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const data = [
    { age: 2, name: 'John' },
    { age: 32,name: 'Mark' },
    { age: 22,name: 'Dell' },
    { age: 14,name: 'Linda' },
    { age: 16,name: 'Jon' },
    { age: 18,name: 'Ron' }
  ];
  const [myData, setMydata] = useState([]);
  const searchData = e => {
    const v = e.target.value;
    const res = data.filter(i =>
      i.name.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase())
    );
    setMydata(res);
  };
  function handleChange(value) {
    const res = data.filter(i => i.age === Number(value.target.value));
    console.log("This is the value and respos", value.target.value);
    setMydata(res);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select defaultValue="" style={{ width: 120 }} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
      </select>

      <input onChange={searchData} />
      <h1>Data</h1>
      {myData.map((i, k) => (
        <div key={k}>
          {i.name} is <span>{i.age}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the codesandbox demo: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-error-4cg7l)